# Generate a query that search with exclude record

Tags: mysql

I'm facing a problem in `mysql` to generate a good query that is consumable in `website`. What I'm doing is if user is logged in a website and try to search for already registered users with keywords like `first_name` ,`last_name` or `username` then i want to give results back, with excluding that user record who is searching. This is `users` table that has a data.

```
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | email           | username | first_name | last_name |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | jim@example.com | jim      | Jim        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 2  | doe@example.com | doe      | Doe        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 3  | tim@a.com       | tim      | Tim        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Assume user with `id` `1` is searching, and he search with a keyword like `john` the query that I'm using for excluding the record of that user is

```
SELECT *
FROM
 `users`
WHERE
    `id` <> 1 AND CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE "%john%" OR `username` LIKE "%john%"
```

then `mysql` give result like this.

```
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | email           | username | first_name | last_name |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 2  | doe@example.com | doe      | Doe        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 3  | tim@a.com       | tim      | Tim        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

But when i search with the username of `id` `1` then why `mysql` doesn't exclude the record

```
SELECT *
FROM
 `users`
WHERE
    `id` <> 1 AND CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE "%jim%" OR `username` LIKE "%jim%"
```

Output result:

```
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | email           | username | first_name | last_name |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | jim@example.com | jim      | Jim        | John      |
+----+-----------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Try this: `WHERE
    `id` <> 1 AND ( CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE "%jim%" OR `username` LIKE "%jim%")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a matter of brackets in your and/or:

```
 `id` <> 1 AND ( CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) LIKE "%jim%" 
                 OR `username` LIKE "%jim%" )
```